# Python - Can Multiple if-condition and append be simplified

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

If it is possible to simplify the following code.

```
c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9 = ([] for _ in range(10))
  
  for i in dataset:
    if i[1] == 0:
      c0.append(i)
    elif i[1] == 1:
      c1.append(i)
    elif i[1] == 2:
      c2.append(i)
    elif i[1] == 3:
      c3.append(i)
    elif i[1] == 4:
      c4.append(i)
    elif i[1] == 5:
      c5.append(i)
    elif i[1] == 6:
      c6.append(i)
    elif i[1] == 7:
      c7.append(i)
    elif i[1] == 8:
      c8.append(i)
    else:
      c9.append(i)
```

Trying to divide the whole dataset into class-wise multiple datasets. Code below is just for example which has only 10 classes, but the dataset I'm working on has massive numbers of classes, so need to simplify as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Better with a list:

```
lsts = [c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8]
for i in dataset:
    if i[1] < len(lsts):
        lsts[i[1]].append(i)
    else:
        c9.append(i)
```

And the lists will contain what you want :)

Comment: note that in OPs code the else contains all numbers not 0-8, yours would fail if there was a 'i[1] == 13' for example.

Comment: @ChristianSloper Edited

Comment: Appreciate a lot. Didn't apply yet but it seems like a better code with time efficiency

Comment: still not correct if i < len(lsts) should be if i[1] < len(lsts)

Comment: @ChristianSloper Ah sorry! Missed it

Comment: @이재환 Does it work?

Answer (score 4):

How about like this?

Use dictionary instead of nested lists like `c0, c1, c2`

```py
c = {x:[] for x in range(10)}
  
for i in dataset:
    c[i[1]].append(i)
```

If you want to append other items in the dataset to the `c9` as like you mentioned in your question, then

```py
for i in dataset:
    if 0 <= i[1] <= 8:
        c[i[1]].append(i)
    else:
        c[9].append(i)
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use it.

```py
# if you need cX as var
c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9 = ([] for _ in range(10))
database = {0: c0,
            1: c1,
            2: c2,
            ...,
            9: c9}

# else
database = {i: [] for i in range(10)}

for i in dataset:
    if i[1] in dataset:
        database[i].append(i)
    else:
        database[9].append(i)
```

Comment: Your solution is incorrect.

Comment: OP is dividing by index *1* not *0*. Your condition is wrong `1 in [[1,0],[2,0]]` is `False`.

Comment: Please tell me where the problem is, let me correct it.

Comment: oh ok I edit it

Comment: database[i] is still incorrect.